# Прогресс отправления файлов base64 c помощью json через XMLHttpRequest javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, base64

Нужно отправлять огромное количество фотографий в base64 на сервер. Хотелось бы отслеживать прогресс передачи, но метод onprogress почему-то всегда показывает **20** байт.

```
const url = 'URL';
const xmr = new XMLHttpRequest();
function test_send(){
  js = {"photo1":"base64_string", "photo2":"base64_string", "photo3":"base64_string"}
  xmr.onprogress = function(event) {
  console.log("Загружено на сервер " + event.loaded  + ' байт из ' + event.total );
}

  xmr.onload =  function (){
      console.log('Completed!');
  }
  xmr.onerror =  function (){
    console.log('ОШИБКА!!!');
  }
  xmr.open("POST", url, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  xmr.send(JSON.stringify(js));
}
test_send();
```

Comment: [`xmr.onprogress` -> `xmr.upload.onprogress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/upload).

Comment: @Yaant , Вы абсолютно правы. Необходимо использовать upload.onprogress.